# How to keep long-lived connections between a Chrome extension and a native messaging host?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I created a Chrome extension and use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#native-messaging) to connect to a C++ native application.

But for every message that the Chrome extension sends to the native host, a new host exe instance is created. I think it is not efficient because I send many messages to the host.

Is there a long-lived connection method between a Chrome extension and a native messaging host?

Comment: How about including your code to connect to the native host?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending the messages with `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage`, or create a new Port object with `chrome.runtime.connectNative` for every message, then yes, it's inefficient.

The purpose of `chrome.runtime.connectNative` is to create and maintain open a message Port, which you can reuse. As long as your native host behaves in a manner Chrome expects and doesn't close the connection itself, it will be a long-lived connection.

```js
function connect(messageHandler, disconnectHandler){
  var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.my_company.my_application');
  if(disconnectHandler) { port.onDisconnect.addListener(disconnectHandler); }
  if(messageHandler) { port.onMessage.addListener(messageHandler); }
  return port;
}

var hostPort = connect(/*...*/);
port.postMessage({ text: "Hello, my_application" });

// Goes to the same instance
port.postMessage({ text: "P.S. I also wanted to say this" });

// If you want to explicitly end the instance
port.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But how should the native do to get every message form the host? I tried a way that make the native host use a while loop to get message from the stdin, it doesn't work. Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Reformulate your question or make another, because from this one it's unclear that you need help with the native host side.  Describe what you tried. There are better experts than me in this.